# Js - Use array variable in parallel function

Tags: javascript, recursion, concurrency, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a recursive function

I call it in parallel with different parameters.

But one counter is a global array and each function change the value of different element.

With a normal array it's impossible do this.

Does a data structure exists for this type of operation?

This is an example of the code.
It is a simplified example but the concept is the same.

Thanks!  :)

```
var counter = [0,1]

function myFunc(index){
  ///do somethings
  if(counter[index] < 3){
    counter[index]++
    myfunc(index)
   }
}


async.parallel([
  function() {
    myFunc(0);
  },
  function() {
    myFunc(1);
  }
]);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check my revision of your question - is it OK?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the revision.

Comment: Can you explain a litte more "With a normal array it's impossible do this". I suggest to expand code, add output, describe desired output. Maybe put on jsfiddle.net or other js playground. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration